# Wordpress Ajax Form with two submit buttons

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am working in wordpress and I have one form and two submit buttons. I am using ajax and it is wordpress.

When first submit button is pressed I want statement 1 to be echoed and when submit button number 2 is pressed I want state 2 be echoed. I have followed the code tutorials but when I press submit from the control returns empty or no result and in inspect there is no error in the browser. Below is my code.

HTML Form

```
<form id="voteform" action="" method="post">
<input  name='vote' value='two' src='http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/up.jpg' type='submit' type='image'>
<input  name='vote' value='one' src='http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/up.jpg' type='submit' type='image'>
</form>
```

I am not copying the enqueue code but just the actual php function that executes

```
function articlevote ()
{

  if ($_POST['vote'] == 'one') {
    echo json_encode("1 vote button is pressed");
    die();
  }
  else if ($_POST['vote'] == 'two') {
    echo json_encode("2 vote button is pressed");
    die();  
  }
}
```

Ajax and jquery

```
    jQuery(function ($) {
    $(document).on("click","input[name=vote]", function() {
    var _data= $('#voteform').serialize() + '&vote=' + $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: yes.ajaxurl,
      data:_data,
      success: function(html){
         $("#myresult").html(res);
      }
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Again kindly note that I am using wordpress so kindly guide me in this thanks

Comment: Are you only passing the value from the button, or does your actual form have more fields?

Comment: my actual form has two more text fields only above these submit buttons.

Comment: where is my function articlevote () mentioned in your code ... because this function is not running with your ajax code

Comment: You cant call your php function `articlevote()` from your jQuery code if that's what you mean. PHP only runs once on page load then it's gone. It's not clear what you have going on in your php code except the function you show above.  I just created a php pag that defines that function then calls the function to create a response. I updated the example page I created so it shows the php code I used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you what you need:

**Html:**

```
<form id="voteform" action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="field1" value="field one value"/>
    <input type="text" name="field2" value="field two value"/>
    <input  class='vote' value='two' src='http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/up.jpg' type='submit' type='image'/>
    <input  class='vote' value='one' src='http://localhost:8080/test/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/up.jpg' type='submit' type='image'/>
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
 jQuery(function($) {
     var yes = {ajaxurl:"mypage.php"}; // created for demo

      $('.vote').click(function(e) {
          e.preventDefault(); // stop the normal submit
          var _data = $('#voteform').serialize()+'&vote=' + $(this).val();
          //alert(_data)
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: yes.ajaxurl,
              data: _data,
              success: function(html) {
                  $("#myresult").html(html); // you had `res` here
              }
          });
      });
  });
```

Comment: Hey ... infact I want to use it with form and use these two buttons as form submit buttons. thanks

Comment: it just refreshes the page with no errors in the console.

Comment: did you change the `name` attribute on the html buttons to `classes`? It should wrk if you changed those, see http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/vote/

Comment: where is my function articlevote () mentioned in your code ... because this function is not running with your ajax code

Comment: is this not missing in your code action : 'articlevote',

Comment: where in the ajax call? I dont think you can do that, see http://dodsoftware.com/sotests/vote/action/ and see the docs at http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: so how can I run a php function I mean a different php code on pressing a different submit button

Comment: wow it worked with  var yes = {ajaxurl:"mypage.php"}; ... thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[value=\'one\'], input[value=\'two\']').on('click', function(){
        var _data= $('#voteform').serialize() + '&vote=' + $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: yes.ajaxurl,
          data:_data,
          success: function(html){
             $("#myresult").html(res);
          }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: prakash it just returns the empty screen and nothing is received and the console has no error

Comment: where to use this action : 'articlevote', .... article vote is the name of my php function ... please guide ... action atribute is not there in your code.